# Find ftsopen No such file or Directory

Tags: bash, unix

I can execute my code in TextMate in mac without problem, but if i try to execute the same code containing this command in the terminal like this "./Test.sh" i have an error:

```
find: ftsopen: No such file or directory
```

code:

```
 dossier="r-repos"
 dossierpath=$(find ./ -name "${dossier}")
 echo "$dossierpath"
```

Do I have to change "./" if i move the file of my script to another folder? Because i have this error only if i move my script.

Many Thanks

Comment: Where are you running that command from? Are you running it from the same file location in terminal and textmate?

Comment: if i run my file from my Desktop in the Terminal there is no problem but if i move the file to another folder there is nothing displayed

Answer (score 0):

`./` refers to the current folder you are executing from.  If you move it to another folder, you it will try to find `$dossier` in the folder you move it to.

Replace `./` with the full path of the folder you're trying to search and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command searches for files in a directory hierarchy. By switching directories to the file/folder you were looking for you were able to find it. In order to have your script search the whole system for r-repos, delete the "." in front of the forward slash.

> find / -name foo
>
> This will search the whole system for any files
>   named foo and display their pathnames.  Here we are using the
>   criterion ‑name with the argument foo to tell find to perform a name
>   search for the filename foo.  The output might look like this:

```
/home/wpollock/foo 
/home/ua02/foo 
/tmp/foo
```

If find doesn't locate any matching files, it produces no output.

Here is an example of an edit I did with your script and a folder titled "Games".

```
#!/bin/bash
dossier="Games"
dossierpath=$(find ./ -name "${dossier}")
echo "$dossierpath"

root@kali:~/Desktop# '/root/Desktop/help'
```

This returns the output blank because there were no files/folders in my desktop names Games.

When i edit the script to not include the . , it will easily find it.

```
#!/bin/bash
dossier="Games"
dossierpath=$(find / -name "${dossier}")
echo "$dossierpath"

root@kali:~/Desktop# '/root/Desktop/help' 
/root/Games
```

With /root/Games being the output.

These two links may offer some additional help if necessary.

http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm

Comment: I have modified my code as: dossierpath=$(find / -name "$dossier"  2>/dev/null) but i have permission denied errors

Comment: Permission denied usually refers to either the script youre running doesn't have permission to run - look up chmod or right click properties > permissions > make sure execute has a check mark - or that you aren't running the scripts as a user with the proper permissions. Try running it as root - su command.

Comment: Searching from `/` is going to cover quite a lot of the filesystem... a good bit of which a normal user is not going to have access to.

Comment: Precisely what Etan said.

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your problem, it would be best to mark it as such for future viewers.